# Mysql: If a field in a record is empty I want the stored procedure to return N/A as value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a table in `MySQL` where in a record a field (Default: None) does not have any value.

I'm using a stored procedure to select values from this table and I when this field has no value I should get the value `N/A`.

I tried the following code but I get the field with no value.

```
SELECT md.coding_id,
    md.patient_id,
    md.implant_date,
    (case 
        when md.device_and_implant_description = ''
            then 'N/A'
        when md.device_and_implant_description !=0
            then md.device_and_implant_description
     end) as device_and_implant_description
FROM medical_devices_mapping as md
WHERE md.patient_id = p_id
```

The `p_id` value is given by the user.

This is the result:
[image]

This is the structure of my table:

[image]

Comment: device_and_implant_description appears twice in select but your output only shows one?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes this is by mistake. I only want the case selection. I will edit my question. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `COALESCE()`.

The proposed solution is the following:

```
SELECT md.coding_id,
    md.patient_id,
    md.implant_date,
    (CASE when COALESCE(md.device_and_implant_description, '') !='' 
         then md.device_and_implant_description
        when COALESCE(md.device_and_implant_description, '') ='' 
         then 'N/A'
     end) as device_and_implant_description
FROM medical_devices_mapping as md
WHERE md.patient_id = p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP` condition instead of `''`

```
SELECT md.coding_id, md.patient_id, md.implant_date,
       CASE WHEN md.device_and_implant_description REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
            THEN md.device_and_implant_description
            ELSE 'N/A'
       END AS device_and_implant_description,
       md.device_and_implant_description
FROM medical_devices_mapping md
WHERE md.patient_id = p_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but the problem remains. The value is not null.

Comment: Since default value is none. Can't you replace `''` with `NONE` (Wild gues)

Comment: @MarkBaijens I tried it by `NONE` is not a recognizable value in mysql stored-procedure.

Comment: I get for both record `N/A` as value. So the else statement is executed for both records.

Answer (score 0):

Please use NUll as well as "".

If you want to use NULL or '' only then before storing data, make sure that you are storing null or empty string then accordingly use condition.

Comment: When I insert data via phpmyadmin is this table in field `device_and_implant_description` I don't write anything.

Comment: Please share table schema which will make clear, if default value is null then it will store NULL.
If you don't specify anything still it will store NULL. So you can use NULL in you SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should invert your logic

```
case when trim(md.device_and_implant_description) is not null then md.device_and_implant_description
else 'N/A'
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck!

Comment: Then check for non-printing characters like line feeds carriage returns etc.